# Uniqueness of real numbers represented as products of integer powers of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

Let $p_k$ represent the $(k+1)$th prime number.  My hypothesis is that all positive real numbers may be represented as some infinite product
$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty p_k^{e_k}$$
(where $e_k \in \mathbb{Z}$); and moreover that this product is unique.  Intuitively I am certain this is true, but I cannot imagine how I could go about proving it.

EDIT: some rational examples for clarity:

$1 = 2^0\cdot3^0\cdot5^0\cdot7^0\cdot11^0\cdot\dots$

$\frac{22}{7} = 2^1\cdot3^0\cdot5^2\cdot7^{-1}\cdot11^1\cdot\dots$

$100 = 2^2\cdot3^0\cdot5^2\cdot7^0\cdot11^0\cdot\dots$

Comment: Even $-14.23213$?

Comment: Apologies! Edited the question

Comment: What might such a product mean?  Say, for example, that all the $e_i=1$.  What number is represented?

Comment: Show me $\sqrt{2}$ and I'll keep reading.

Comment: There would need to be alternating positive and negative exponents for the number to be finite.

Comment: Ok.  Suppose $e_i=(-1)^i$.  Now what number is represented?

Comment: This is the reason for the question: I can't generalize it to irrationals, although I'm intuitively sure that is the case.

Comment: My point is that your product only appears to be defined if $e_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i$.  If so, all you get is the set of positive rationals.

Comment: Surely, for Randall's example, there exists some sequence of positive and negative powers of primes that converges to $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Usually an infinite product $P=\Pi a_i$ is defined via $\log P=\sum \log {a_i}$.  But for that definition to be useful, we need the series to converge, which implies that $\log {a_i}$ tends to $0$ which means that $a_i$ tends to $1$ which, in your case, means that the $e_i$ have to become $0$ at some point.

Comment: Now, I think a *legitimate* question is, if you apply some *unconventional* methods of summation (e.g. Cesàro summation: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{e_i}}$) - whether it will *sometimes* converge, and to what. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @user8734617: more naively, you can also just ask whether the sequence of partial products $p_n = \prod_1^n x_i$ converges. This does not require $x_i$ to tend to $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan Of course it does. If $p_n\to p$, then $p_{n-1}\to p$ so $x_n=\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}\to\frac{p}{p}=1$, except when $p=0$, which is not a very interesting case here.

Comment: @user8734617; sure,I understand that, but it is a significant technical detail that seems always to get forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite product $\prod x_i$ of real (and also complex) numbers converges only if the sequence $(x_i)$ converges to 1. In your case you have to have $p_i^{e_i} \to 1$. Which is only possible if $(e_i)$ is eventually vanishing.

Comment: You are right that the standard definition of convergence of an infinite product requires the terms to converge to $1$. However, that is just a definition made for convenience: the sequence of partial products $p_n = \prod_{1}^{n}x_i$ can converge when $x_i$ does not tend to $1$ (e.g., $x_i = 1/i$ or $x_i = i - 1$).

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, but that allows only $0$ as additional limit

Comment: If all the exponents are all negative doesn't the product converge to 0 quite quickly?

Comment: @SupBro Yes you're right. However as mentioned [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen) that only adds zero as a limit... The irrational numbers are out of rich with those infinite products.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The product will not converge unless almost all exponents are zero. In other words, you get exactly the *positive rational numbers*.